# yandex-geocoding-api

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мы используем модуль ЯндексКарт (yandex-maps-api) при разработке своего сайта, вопрос: может ли данный модуль размещаться в закрытом разделе своего сайта?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/
2.3.3 Сервис может использоваться Пользователем только в рамках сайтов или приложений, доступных для бесплатного открытого использования неограниченным кругом лиц. Сервис не может использоваться для проектов, требующих оплаты, или иным образом ограничивающих доступ к ним третьих лиц. Необходимость зарегистрироваться не считается ограничением доступа в рамках настоящего пункта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Условия бесплатного использования написаны в [мануале](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index.html).
Если на сайте есть регистрация, то она должна быть доступна всем желающим.